How to avoid infinite loop when trying to update nested fieldArray with react hook form?
I'm getting an infinite loop when trying to update the total inside a table that uses the useFieldArray hook from react hook form.
  const items = useWatch({
    control,
    name: "items",
  });

  const { fields, ...fieldsProps } = useFieldArray({
    control: control,
    name: "items",
  });

  const controlledFields = fields.map((field, index) => {
    return {
      ...field,
      ...items[index],
    };
  });

I have an itemTable component where I pass the props:
      <ItemTable
              form={form}
              control={control}
              controlledFields={controlledFields}
              data={items}
              fieldsProps={fieldsProps}
              isTaxInclusive={tax_inclusive}
              isDiscountItemLevel={is_discount_item_level}
            />

Inside the ItemTable component i have a renderItemRow function where the infinite loop occurs:
  function renderItemRow(item, key) {
    const quantity = item.quantity;
    const discountPercentage = item.discount_percentage || 0;
    const discountAmount = item.discount_amount || 0;
    const price = item.unit_price || 0;

    // Calculate total discount
    const discountTotal =
      discountAmount > 0
        ? discountAmount * quantity
        : (discountPercentage / 100) * price * quantity;

    const itemTotal = quantity * price - discountTotal;

    update(key, {       // <-- infinite loop
      total: itemTotal, 
    });

my goal is to display and update the correct item total whenever the user changes the quantity, price or tax percentage of a certain item:
    <td id="total" className={`${styles.rowItem} w-[115px] px-2 font-bold`}>
          <FormField
            control={control}
            name={`items[${key}].total`}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    readOnly
                    variant="ghost"
                    className="text-right text-black"
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />


For the same reason you do not update a state at a component's top level... You are always updating the total on each render.

since you haven't shared the ItemTable code, i can only assume "renderItemRow" is called in the body to mutate the data without returning a value.  this means it will be rerendered because the props passed into it are different, causing a loop.  instead, simply display the formatted data without changing it with the "update" function.
const ItemTable = ({ items }) => {
    return (
        <table>
        <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
                const quantity = item.quantity;
                const discountPercentage = item.discount_percentage || 0;
                const discountAmount = item.discount_amount || 0;
                const price = item.unit_price || 0;

                // Calculate total discount
                const discountTotal =
                  discountAmount > 0
                    ? discountAmount * quantity
                    : (discountPercentage / 100) * price * quantity;

                const itemTotal = quantity * price - discountTotal;
                return (<tr><td>Total = ${itemTotal}  and the other stuff in the row </td></tr>)
            })
        </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}

the child component should not be changing the original data at all since you set it as readonly.  just change how it displays the data.  if the form is set up correctly, the changes should be reflected when the user changes the inputs, not when your input does so by itself on render.  when the backing data changes, your child component once again just accepts the props and displays the total based on a calculation, not by mutating the data with the calculation.
